# How to make multiple select into on the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i got a little problem right now i'm doing Stored Proc in sql server. I wanna get some result from multiple table and put it into a temporary table. So I thought  i could use a "Select into" statement wich work fine until i decided to add multiple select into the temporary table. For example: Here's my code:

```
while @Compteur <= @wrhCodeEnd
  select lp.lotQty ,lp.lotID into ZeTable from TB_lotLot ltlt
  inner join TB_lotPal lp on ltlt.lotID=lp.lotID
  inner join TB_palSuper ps ON lp.spID=ps.spID
  inner join TB_expExpeditionLot eel ON eel.lotID=lp.spID
  where ps.wrhID <> @Compteur and
   ltlt.wrhID = @Compteur and
   lp.lotID not in(select ZeTable.lotID from ZeTable)
```

the thing is  I don't know if I can make multiple select into on the same temporary table and I also wanna check with a where clause the information in the table is not already there.

Thx in Advance

Comment: The typical way of doing "select result from multiple table into temporary table is" is to do a INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM. Not looping. You're in a RDMBS, *use* its set-based processing.

Comment: Right, you cannot use SELECT INTO to insert into a table that already exists. as @NWest says, you must use INSERT INTO ... SELECT. I will second that you should attempt to use set based logic if it makes sense for your application.

Comment: Ok thx guy for your answer. I've create a temporary table and i'm adding my select with insert into and its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create temporary table and can use insert statement to add records with required columns and can drop it after use.

Comment: Ok but if i wanna add the whole select into my table how can i do that? Can I just do a INSERT INTO ##table values(select * from blabla)

Comment: Yes, you can use,  insert into #temptable select * from #DBTable.  but your #temp should have same columns as #DBTable.